# получение id текущего пользователя flask_login

Tags: flask

У меня есть функция создания сессии авторизированного пользователя вида:

```
class UserLogin():
    def fromDB(self, user_id, db):
        my_users = db.query.all()
        for user in my_users:
            if user_id == user.id:
                self.__user = user.user
        return self

    def Create(self, user):
        self.__user = user
        return self

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonimus(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.__user.id)
```

Загружаю пользователей я таким образом:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return UserLogin().fromDB(user_id, Users)
```

Выходит, что когда я в шаблоне использую {{current_user}}, я получаю объект класса UserLogin. Вопрос заключается в том, **как получить из возвращаемого объекта id пользователя**.

Я пробовал `UserLogin().fromDB(user_id, Users).get_id()` через backend и `{{current_user.get_id()}}` в шаблоне, но получал `AttributeError: 'UserLogin' object has no attribute '_UserLogin__user'`. Больше в голову ничего не приходит.

Comment: Если в `user_loader` метод `fromDB` уже и так был вызван, то наверное достаточно просто `{{current_user.get_id()}}` да и всё?

Comment: Если бы! всё та же ошибка.

Comment: Тогда, может быть, метод `fromDB` не смог найти пользователя? Проверьте, какой конкретно `user_id` там передаётся, какой конкретно тип он имеет (строка, число, что-нибудь ещё) и является ли его поиск в базе успешным

Comment: Да, действительно, хватило просто изменить тип user_id на int. Глупая ошибка, без вашей помощи никогда бы не обратил внимания, большое спасибо)